# How to handle custom failover scenarios in gRPC (C++)?

Tags: c++, load-balancing, grpc, failover

gRPC is really good at failover scenarios when used with 'pick_first'. However, I would like to implement more custom failover scenarios.

Assume that I have 2 servers and 1 client. I would like to apply "Client side LB options" stated in [link](https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-load-balancing/).

When I implement using the "pick_first" policy and with related IP addresses of servers, it works perfectly. But, I may want to change the used server for some reasons. I would like to describe the custom failover scenario.

Custom Failover Scenario

1. Server 1 and Server 2 is up
2. Client connects to the Server 1
3. Server 1 is down, client connects to Server 2
4. Server 1 is up again, the client is still connected to Server 2
5. I love Server 1 :) I want the client to connect to Server 1 again for some reason. However, it only connects to Server 1 again when Server 2 is disconnected.

1 to 4 items are already can be implemented easily with default gRPC. I could not find a good path to implement 5. item.

I also would like to know whether should I use "Thick client-side load balancing" or "Look-aside Load Balancing" for the custom failover scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your resolver always returns the address of server 1 before the address of server 2, then you can probably get what you want by using the max connection age feature on the server side, as described here:

https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/A9-server-side-conn-mgt.md

Whenever the server disconnects, the client will try to reconnect starting from the first address in the list.  So if you have your server disconnect every N minutes, then that defines an upper bound on the amount of time it will take for the client to switch back to server 1.

The down-side of the above approach is that when you're using pick_first, there will be a latency blip whenever the server disconnects, because the client will need to reconnect before it can continue to send RPCs.

A better approach would be to write a custom LB policy for this.  But unfortunately, gRPC C++ does not currently have a public LB policy API.  That's something we've been wanting to do for a while, but it's blocked on some work that we're doing to change our event loop APIs, since the current event loop APIs require some internal stuff in the LB policy APIs that we don't want to expose.

Another alternative would be to use a look-aside load balancing control plane for this.  For example, if you had a control plane speaking either the old grpclb or the new xDS APIs, you could have the control plane check whether server 1 was up and use that to decide whether the client should talk to server 1 or server 2.

I hope this information is helpful.